# pass an image from one view controller to another (swift) with Firebase

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

i am trying to pass an image from one view controller to another but i am getting an error in prepare for segue function

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        let post = posts[indexPath.row]

        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)as? collectionViewCellBooks {

            if let img = booksVC.imageCache.object(forKey: post.imageUrl as NSString) {
                cell.configureCell(post: post, img: img)
                return cell

        }else {

                cell.configureCell(post: post)
                return cell
            }
        }
            else {
                return collectionViewCellBooks()
            }

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showImage", sender: self)
    }



    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {

         if segue.identifier == "showImage"
         {

         let indexPaths = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems!
         let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as IndexPath
         let vc = segue.destination as! newViewController
        // vc.image = self.posts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
            vc.image = self.posts[indexPath.row]
         }





class newViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    var image = UIImage()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.imageView.image = self.image
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

this is my Post class

class Post {

```
private var _caption: String!
private var _imageUrl: String!
private var _postKey: String!



var caption: String {
    return _caption
}

var imageUrl: String {
    return _imageUrl
}

var postKey: String {
    return _postKey
}


init(caption: String, imageUrl: String) {

    self._caption = caption
    self._imageUrl = imageUrl
}

init(postKey: String, postData: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {

    self._postKey = postKey

    if let caption = postData["title"] as? String {
        self._caption = caption
    }
    if let imagesUrl = postData["imageURL"] as? String {
        self._imageUrl = imagesUrl
    }

}
```

}

title and imageURL are saved on firebase database

Comment: mention error in your question.

Comment: the error i am getting because of this line "vc.image = self.posts[indexPath.row]"    cannot assign value of type "Post" to type 'UIimage'

Comment: which kind of data contained in self.posts.

Comment: if (segue.identifier == "CollectionToDetail")
    {
        let DealsdetailViewController = segue.destination as! newViewController
                    
         DealsdetailViewController.YOURIMAGENAME =  "PASS IMAGE NAME OR URL"
    }

Comment: Himanshu Moradiya, i can't do that because all the images are in array and they are all saved on firebase

Comment: vc.image = self.posts[indexPath.row] why you uses then like this ?

Comment: i know that this is wrong, i don't know how to fix it you can use that if you have the pictures saved on your app not in a database

Comment: @tom do one thing just past array from seguge and in next controller reterive it and assign image to imageview .

Comment: vc.image = self.posts[indexPath.row] in this you declare one property in nextcontroller with nsarray and pass it and in next controller reterive it and assign it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with following change in preparefor segue method.. let me know

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    {

         if segue.identifier == "showImage"
         {

         let indexPaths = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems!
         let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as IndexPath
         let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! newViewController

         let post = posts[indexPath.row]
         if let img = booksVC.imageCache.object(forKey: post.imageUrl as NSString) {
                vc.image = img
         }
       }
    }


class newViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    var image = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if self.image {
         self.imageView.image = self.image
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x10e41bdd8) to 'almostshar2.newViewController' (0x10a4e27b8).   error in this line             let vc = segue.destination as! newViewController   Thread 1:signal SIGABRT

Comment: you are right i did that and i set the class in the storyboard in nextcontroller but i got another error in newViewController for that line         self.imageView.image = self.image  the error is fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because you are not sending an image to the new viewController but an instance of your Post class, which by the way doesn't even contain an image (only an imageURL). You have to extract the image from the server first before you can parse it anywhere.

You should parse the whole post as you are doing it right now and download the image via the postID directly in the new ViewController. (in case you saved the image in Firebase storage) I always end up parseing the whole object because later in the development you maybe decide to show more properties in the newViewController. If you parsed the whole object you don't have to change your code structure anymore.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "your Identifier" {
            if let vc = segue.destination as?  NewViewController {
                if let post = sender as? Post {
                    vc.post = post
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

in your didSelectIdemAt function you need to change the sender of the performSegue function:

```
 performSegue(withIdentifier: "your Identifier", sender: post)
```

now your newViewController has a little bit more code but that is how i do it and it works stable.

```
let reference = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
reference.child("posts").child("<postID>").observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
print(snapshot.value)

if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
    for snap in snapshots {

        if let postsDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

            if let imageURL = postsDict["imageURL"] as? String {
                let httpsReference = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: imageURL)
                httpsReference.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("error... couldn't get picture from Server \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    } else {
                        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        self.img = image! // you need to create this variable somewhere in your viewController Class before this code
                        //"your UIImageVIew.image" = img AND THAT IS IT
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```